# Segmentaton Fault (core dumped) in c programming

Tags: c, unix

I have simple c app where I have server which I run first and then try to execute my c programm and I am getting this error segmentation fault core dumped. I think the problem might come from my allocation memory but have no idea if it is from there how to repar it: Bellow is my code:

```
    /* This is student.c file which as a part of MAD assignment 1 is referenced and used in main.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#include "config.h" // auto generated
#include "customer.h"


Customer *make_customer(unsigned id)
{

  Customer *cust;

  if ((cust = (Customer *)malloc(sizeof(Customer))) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate Customer structure!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  cust->active = 0;
  cust->id = id;
  cust->old = NULL;
  cust->address = NULL;
  cust->name = NULL;

  return cust;
}

void free_customer(Customer *cust)
{
  free(cust->old);
  free(cust->address);
  free(cust->name);
  free(cust);
}

void make_customer_active(Customer *cust)
{
  cust->active = 1;
}


void set_customer_old(Customer *cust, char *old)
{
  cust->old = strdup(old);
}

void set_customer_address(Customer *cust, char *address)
{
  cust->address = strdup(address);
}

void set_customer_name(Customer *cust, char *name)
{
  cust->name = strdup(name);
}

int is_customer_active(Customer *cust)
{
  return cust->active;
}

int serialize_customer(char *buffer, Customer *cust)
{
  size_t offset = 0;

  memcpy(buffer, &cust->id, sizeof(cust->id));
  offset = sizeof(cust->id);
  memcpy(buffer+offset, &cust->active, sizeof(cust->active));
  offset = offset + sizeof(cust->active);
  memcpy(buffer+offset, cust->old, strlen(cust->old)+1);
  offset = offset + strlen(cust->old)+1;
  memcpy(buffer+offset, cust->address, strlen(cust->address)+1);
  offset = offset + strlen(cust->address)+1;
  memcpy(buffer+offset, cust->name, strlen(cust->name)+1);
  offset = offset + strlen(cust->name)+1;


  return offset;
}

int deserialize_customer(char *buffer, Customer *cust)
{
  size_t offset = 0;

  memcpy(&cust->id, buffer, sizeof(cust->id));
  offset = sizeof(cust->id);
  memcpy(&cust->active, buffer+offset, sizeof(cust->active));
  offset = offset + sizeof(cust->active);
  memcpy(cust->name, buffer+offset, strlen(buffer+offset)+1);
  offset = offset + strlen(buffer+offset)+1;


  return offset;
}

void print_customer(Customer *cust)
{
  printf("Customer id:%d\n", cust->id);
  printf("Cutomer age:%s\n", cust->old);
  printf("Cutomer name:%s\n", cust->name);
  printf("Cutomer address:%s\n", cust->address);
}

Customer *alloc_blank_customer() 
{

  Customer *cust;

  if ((cust = (Customer *)malloc(sizeof(Customer))) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate Customer structure!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  cust->active = 0;
  cust->id = 0;
  if ((cust->name = malloc(MAX_NAME)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate name!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if ((cust->old = malloc(MAX_OLD)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate age!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if ((cust->address = malloc(MAX_ADDRESS)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate address!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  return cust;
 }}}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Voting to close as "too localized" because it's very unlikely that anyone would benefit from this question in the future.

Comment: compile  `$gcc -g <program_name>` ,then `$gdb a.out` , then type `run`. It will help you in pinpointing where exactly the problem (a bad access) is happening.

Comment: You must learn to minimize your code; it is a vital skill. Simply the code a little, and see if the problem persists. If it does, then simplify some more; if it doesn't, then the thing you just removed was part of the problem, so restore it. Either you will find the problem, or you will arrive at a very small and simple example to show us. And when you write code, do this in reverse: start small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, and test at every step.

Comment: Also: [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). I understand that if you're writing C, learning to use that tool is more or less mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted a full program so its not possible to say where your problem lies.  One bug in the code which could cause a seg fault is that `alloc_blank_customer` allocates memory for the various char arrays but doesn't initialise it.  If you later use string handling functions on these uninitialised arrays, the effect will be undefined with a crash possible.

You could fix this by using `calloc` to allocate the char arrays:

```
cust->name = calloc(1, MAX_NAME);
```

or by adding a nul terminator at the start of the array:

```
cust->name = malloc(MAX_NAME);
cust->name[0] = '\0';
```